# Unlist gives me a longer vector than expected

Tags: r, list, content-length

I am performing an RNA-seq analysis and I need a logical vector, however I am starting from a SimpleLogicalList called `hk` with 58037 elements, that I obtained from `hk <- features.info$symbol %in% house_keeping_genes` where `features.info` is a dataframe and `house_keeping_genes` is a vector.

After using `unlist(hk)` 58731 elements are retrieved. Then I realized that there were parts of the list that contained more than two elements (in stead of just `FALSE`, it contained `FALSE` `FALSE` `FALSE`, thus increasing the length of the result.

Then I just used a `unlist(unique(hk))` and most of the unexpected variables were dropped, however there were still 58041 elements in stead of 58037 and I have no idea where are they coming from. I checked and there are no `NA` being generated.

What could I do to find where those 4 extra elements are coming from?

```
> dput(hk[60:70])
new("SimpleLogicalList", elementType = "logical", elementMetadata = NULL, 
    metadata = list(), listData = list(ENSG00000004777 = FALSE, 
        ENSG00000004779 = FALSE, ENSG00000004799 = FALSE, ENSG00000004809 = FALSE, 
        ENSG00000004838 = FALSE, ENSG00000004846 = FALSE, ENSG00000004848 = FALSE, 
        ENSG00000004864 = FALSE, ENSG00000004866 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE), ENSG00000004897 = TRUE, ENSG00000004939 = FALSE))

> dput(features.info$symbol[1:5])
new("SimpleCharacterList", elementType = "character", elementMetadata = NULL, 
    metadata = list(), listData = list(ENSG00000000003 = "TSPAN6", 
        ENSG00000000005 = "TNMD", ENSG00000000419 = "DPM1", ENSG00000000457 = "SCYL3", 
        ENSG00000000460 = "C1orf112"))

> dput(house_keeping_genes[1:5])
c("DPM1", "SCYL3", "GCLC", "BAD", "LAP3")
```

Edit:  I need the logical vector to use it as an argument for `RUVg()`
function and if I write hk an error is retrieved: `> Error in Ycenter[, cIdx] : invalid subscript type 'S4'`.

Packages:

```
other attached packages:
 [1] NCmisc_1.1.6                RUVSeq_1.28.0               EDASeq_2.28.0               ShortRead_1.52.0           
 [5] GenomicAlignments_1.30.0    Rsamtools_2.10.0            Biostrings_2.62.0           XVector_0.34.0             
 [9] snpStats_1.44.0             Matrix_1.4-0                survival_3.2-13             sva_3.42.0                 
[13] BiocParallel_1.28.3         genefilter_1.76.0           mgcv_1.8-38                 nlme_3.1-153               
[17] pheatmap_1.0.12             ggfortify_0.4.14            ggplot2_3.3.5               edgeR_3.36.0               
[21] limma_3.50.0                dplyr_1.0.7                 SummarizedExperiment_1.24.0 GenomicRanges_1.46.1       
[25] GenomeInfoDb_1.30.0         IRanges_2.28.0              S4Vectors_0.32.3            MatrixGenerics_1.6.0       
[29] matrixStats_0.61.0          tweeDEseqCountData_1.32.0   Biobase_2.54.0              BiocGenerics_0.40.0
```

Comment: Can you try `hk1 <- sapply(features.info$symbol, \(x) any(x %in% house_keeping_genes, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! Could you explain how is \(x) working? Is it like defining a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be that some of the `symbol` (which is a `SimpleLogicalList`) contains more than one element, so we loop over the `list` with `sapply`, and wrap with `any` which returns a single TRUE/FALSE if any of the elements in the `list` element are present `%in%` 'house_keeping_genes.  The `\(x)` is a concise way to represent lambda function (`function(x)`) in the recent versions of `R`

```
hk1 <- sapply(features.info$symbol, \(x) 
         any(x %in% house_keeping_genes, na.rm = TRUE))
```